# jquery form validation ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, validation

I have read a few threads and look round the web but still haven't found a solution.

I want to validate a form using jquery but the way in which the asp.net page is built is different from examples round the web.

The whole page is wrapped in a from tag and not the actual individual form.

The only way I have found so far is to use this plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ but to attached a click event rather than the prefer onsubmit. Is there way way to use onsubmit with .net controls?

Many thanks for any assistance.
C

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?  You can't have nested form tags, so are you trying to validate only a portion of the form, or something else?

Comment: The validation plugin is quite flexible, and is pretty much the standard for jquery validation. What are you trying to do?

Comment: In .Net there aren't nested form tags. The whole page is wrapped in a form and controls within the page used to submit to different forms within the page